# Firebase RemoteConfig with RxJava

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, rx-java2, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to use RxJava with FirebaseRemoteConfig but not sure how to make the two work, tried using `Completable` but I get an error `The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with.`

I have this problem where I need to fetch from RemoteConfig then initialize the String variable from MySingleton.class with this latest config to be use later. The said String  variable must not be null or empty so the flow would be.

During Splash

1. Call `fetchAndActivate`
2. Listen for both OnSuccess and OnFailure
3. If success initialize the static String variable with the latest config
4. If failed try to use old/cached configs
5. Cache might not exist yet specially on first run so check if the static String variable is empty
6. If empty show `AlertDialog` for retry.
7. If not proceed to main activity.

What I am trying to do is to use RxJava and listen for OnSuccess or OnFailure listeners, which I can probably apply as well when getting just a single document when using Firebase Firestore in the future.

How can I do this?

So far this is what I got

```
class RemoteConfig {

companion object {

    private val remoteConfig: FirebaseRemoteConfig by lazy {
        FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance()
    }

    private val remoteConfigSettings: FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings by lazy {
        FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(1800)
            .build()
    }

    fun init(context: Context): Completable {
        remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(remoteConfigSettings)

        return Completable.create {
            fetchConfig(context)
        }

    }

    private fun fetchConfig(context: Context): Completable {

        return Completable.create { emitter ->

            remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnSuccessListener {
                //Use the latest configuration
                assignSource(context)
                emitter.onComplete()
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                //Try to use old configuration instead
                assignSource(context)
                emitter.onError(it.cause!!)
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(it)
            }

        }

    }

    private fun assignSource(context: Context) {
        Singleton.staticVariable=
            remoteConfig.getString(context.getString(R.string.key))
    }

}

}
```

Splash activity

```
Completable.mergeArray(
        RemoteConfig.init(this).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribe({
            proceedToMain()
        }, {
            if (Singleton.staticVariable.isEmpty())
                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(it.message)
                    .setPositiveButton("Retry"
                    ) { dialog, _ ->
                        run {
                            dialog.dismiss()
                            fetchConfig()
                        }
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton("Exit"
                    ) { dialog, _ ->
                        dialog.dismiss()
                        finish()
                    }
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show()
            else
                proceedToMain()
        })
```

Comment: You need to fetch every 30 min when the app in foreground?

Comment: No, will update the question. I also manage to make it work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to make it work it seems all I need is to use `tryOnError` since it will automatically handle the case when the emitter get disposed/canceled or no longer available. Instead of `Completable` using just `Observable` is okay too.

```
fun init(context: Context): Observable<Boolean> {

            remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(remoteConfigSettings)

            return Observable.create { emitter ->

                remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnSuccessListener {
                    //Use the latest configuration
                    assignSource(context)
                    Log.wtf("CONFIG", "SUCCESS")
                    emitter.onNext(it)
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    //Try to use old configuration instead
                    assignSource(context)
                    Log.wtf("CONFIG", "FAILED")
                    emitter.tryOnError(it.cause!!) // Try to throw an error if emitter still available or if the sequence is not cancelled/disposed
                    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(it)
                }.addOnCompleteListener {
                    emitter.onComplete()
                    Log.wtf("CONFIG", "COMPLETE")
                }

            }

        }
```

Splash

```
cryptonHadItsChance = RemoteConfig.init(this)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                proceedToMain()
            }, {
                //Only show dialog if necessary field is not available and activity still running
                if (Singleton.staticVariable.isEmpty() && !isFinishing && !isDestroyed)
                    alertDialog.show()
                else
                    proceedToMain()
            })
```